# Moving Player Around SDL_Rect c++

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to make a very basic game. I'm having problems moving the player because SDL_Rect does not store floats. The player is moving to fast so I was trying to increase the speed by a decimal not 1. So is there a way to render in sdl without using SDL_Rect I'm sorry i'm very new to sdl. Player Code:

```
#include "Player.h"


Player::Player() : speed(0.5)
{
    plr.w = 50;
    plr.h = 50;
    plr.x = 10;
    plr.y = 10;
}


Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::input(int key)
{
    if (key == 0)
    {
        left = true;
    }

    if (key == 4)
    {
        left = false;
    }

}

void Player::render(SDL_Renderer* ren)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(ren, &plr);
}

void Player::tick()
{
    if (left)
    {
        plr.x++;
    }
}
```

Any criticism is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always store the position outside of the `SDL_Rect`.

```
float positionX = 0.0f;

void Player::tick()
{
    if (left)
    {
        positionX += speed;
    }
}
```

Then when it comes time to render, round the position to the nearest pixel.

```
#include <math.h>

void Player::render(SDL_Renderer* ren)
{
    plr.x = (int)round(positionX);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(ren, &plr);
}
```

If you want sub-pixel percision, you'll need to move onto something more sophisticated than `SDL_Renderer`. (OpenGL, DirectX, etc.)